# How to export the start of a tenant name in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I need to create a CSV file and export it into a folder.

These are our requirements...

- Folder name needs to be the Office 365 tenant name.
- CSV file name needs to be tenant name.
- Tenant name needs to be the bit before ".onmicrosoft.com".

This is how far I've got

```
$identity = Get-OrganizationConfig | Select identity
Export-Csv <path>\$identity.csv
```

The file name is `"@{Identity=COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com}.csv`.

How do I select the start of the tenant name?

Comment: `Select identity` -> `Select -Expand identity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that `Select-Object Identity` creates a new object with an `Identity` property. If you just want the value of the `Identity` property, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
$identity = Get-OrganizationConfig | Select -ExpandProperty Identity
```

To remove the last part of the tenant FQDN, you could use the `-replace` regex operator:

```
$identity = $identity -replace '\.onmicrosoft\.com$'
```

or the `String.Replace()` method:

```
$identity = $identity.Replace('.onmicrosoft.com')
```

If you want to capitalize the first letter in the tenant name, you could use `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase()`:

```
$identity = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($identity)
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you this works perfectly. 

In addition to this, what would make this look even more professional (but not essential), is to capitalize/CamalCase the start of the company name! Is there a method of doing this after removing the ".onicrosoft.com" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$identity = (Get-OrganizationConfig | Select identity).identity
Export-Csv <path>\$identity.csv
```